How to get parameter value from a templated class
Out of convenience I defined 1d, 2d, 3d and 4d vectors using Eigen::Matrix.
namespace MyNamespace {
    template <class scalar_t, int dim>
    using Vec = Eigen::Matrix<scalar_t, dim, 1, Eigen::ColMajor | Eigen::AutoAlign, dim, 1>;

    typedef Vec<double, 1> Vec1d;  // Convenience typedef for 1d vector of doubles.
    typedef Vec<double, 2> Vec2d;  // Convenience typedef for 2d vector of doubles.
    typedef Vec<double, 3> Vec3d;  // Convenience typedef for 3d vector of doubles.
    typedef Vec<double, 4> Vec4d;  // Convenience typedef for 4d vector of doubles.
}

I then defined a templated class, which should be able to store the dimension dim as en enumerable:
namespace MyNamespace {
/**
 * A class representing Monomial basis.
 */
template <typename vec_t>
class Monomials {
  public:
    typedef vec_t vector_t;   ///< Vector type.
    /// Store dimension of the domain.
    enum { /** Dimensionality of the domain. */ dim = vec_t::dim };

  public:
    /**
     * Construct a basis of all monomials
    */
    Monomials(int order){
        printf("order: %d", order);
        printf("dimension: %d", vec_t::dim); // < ------ I want this!
    };
};
}

However, this does not compile (reproduceable here: https://godbolt.org/z/ro7fn6o3f)
using namespace  MyNamespace;    

int main(){
    auto p = Vec2d{0.0, 1.0};

    printf("%f, %f\n", p[0], p[1]);
    auto m = Monomials<Vec2d>(2);

    return 0;
}

Instead, I get an error saying that
<source>:21:62: error: 'dim' is not a member of 'Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>'

How should it work?
Well all I want is basically to get some sort of Vec2d::dim functionality, that would return me the dimension of a given vector, in this case 2.

I don't understand why you define your own typedefs instead of using the predefined types or simply writing using Vec4d = Eigen::Vector4d. Anyway, Eigen types contain enums with the relevant information such as SizeAtCompileTime which should do exactly what you want.

As the error says, Eigen::Matrix doesn't have a dim value. It does have a RowsAtCompileTime member though

The error message is crystal clear... You should always read the documentation for what you use, there is no reason an implementation would provide what you expect it to provide.

You can use RowsAtCompileTime
printf("dimension: %d", vec_t::RowsAtCompileTime);

With this I'm able to get your example to print
0.000000, 1.000000
order: 2dimension: 2

